A function with multiple extremes from a function with a single extremum through reversible variable replacement
I recently studied normalizing flows, a machine learning method. I was wondering if it is possible to reproduce the illustrations that I often see in articles using this method.
Example
The theory of machine learning is not so important, but the question is how to create a distribution of a single variable with multiple modes from a normal distribution of a single variable using an invertible function to change variable.
Assuming that each $z_i$ and $x$ are just single variables and not vectors, can we construct an $f(z)$ that is invertible and creates a function with multiple maxima from one with only one maximum?
In theory, such a function should be monotonic and therefore cannot generate a function with more than one maximum from a single maximum.
I graduated from a bachelor's degree program a long time ago, so I have forgotten a significant amount of the course material on calculus, and as a result, my reasoning may be very incorrect. I am unable to seek help from anyone else, so I am turning to you for assistance.Sure, I'm not looking for a detailed lecture. Just some links and a quick explanation would be great.
